# How can I interpret this validation testing code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "product attributes must not be empty" do
    product = Product.new
    assert product.invalid?
    assert product.errors[:title].any?
    assert product.errors[:description].any?
    assert product.errors[:price].any?
    assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
  end
end
```

Hi all. I'm pretty new to Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to create a simple online book store. I have a product model that needs to be tested. I'm trying to understand this code in "English" but I'm confused. So, the model needs to contain the :title, :description, :price, :image_url correct?

Are we simply trying to test if all these attributes exist within the Product model?

Thank you all.

Comment: "Are we simply trying to test if all these attributes exist within the Product model?" Yes, you are testing that a product is invalid if it does not have those attributes and it should contain error messages resulting from validation failures on those attributes, however I you need to have `product.save` after `product = Product.new`

Comment: Hi bjhaid. Thank you for your quick response. Could you clarify the "product.save" part? I guess it will also test to see if saved products contain given attributes? Thanks.

Comment: to trigger validations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test assumes the `Product` model has some validations in place.

The test starts on the line

```
product = Product.new
```

where you create a new product. Then you first triggers the validations calling `invalid?` that returns true if the instance is invalid and populates the `errors` list.

```
product.invalid?
```

The assert before makes the test fail if the result of the parameter is false. In this case the parameter is the result of the validation.

```
assert(product.invalid?)
```

If `product.invalid?` would return false it means the product is valid, that means the validation didn't take place, which is not what you are expecting.

Then the code checks every single attribute that is expected to have an error to see if the error was set.

`product.errors` contains the list of errors where the key is the invalid attribute, the value is an array or nil if the attribute is valid.

```
assert product.errors[:description].any?
```

for instance means that you expect the description attribute to be invalid and in fact you check if there is at least one error set.

---

I personally don't really like the approach of that test because it's partially incomplete (you don't actually test the real validation making impossible to understand why the specific attribute is invalid), however it's definitely a good starting point for a simple application.